# Converting World Coordinates to Yaw and Pitch in Lua

Tags: lua, 3d, coordinates, fivem, aim

Okay I have calculated (in LUA) the position of the player's bones.

```
local TargetCoords = GetPedBoneCoords("PED", 31086, 0, 0, 0)
```

then I get my camera position (vec3)

```
local cam = GetFinalRenderedCamCoord()
```

and these are the calculations I made to get Yaw and pitch from that coords.

```
local dX = TargetCoords.x - cam.x;
local dY = TargetCoords.y - cam.y;
local dZ = TargetCoords.z - cam.z;

local pitch = math.atan2(math.sqrt(dZ * dZ + dX * dX), dY) + math.pi
local yaw = math.atan2(dZ, dX)
local roll = 0.0
```

The numbers I get are from 0 to 5 but these are not valid yaw and pitch.

The Yaw goes from 60.0 to -60.0 and the pitch goes from -180 to 180 (or 0 to 360 both valid).

**EDIT**

Tried also different formulas

```
local dX = TargetCoords.x - cam.x;
local dY = TargetCoords.y - cam.y;
local dZ = TargetCoords.z - cam.z;

local dVL = math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY + dZ * dZ)

local pitch = math.asin(dZ / dVL) 
local yaw   = math.atan2(dY, dZ) 
local roll  = 0.0

pitch = (math.deg(pitch) + 180) % 360 - 180
yaw = (math.deg(yaw) + 180) % 360 - 180
```

I get different numbers but it's not the target position on screen. Is it the right triagle?

*P.S. I'm new in lua so I tried to check some formulas but it's not clear to me.*

**EXAMPLE**

These are the target coords -> *vector3(-1694.083, -218.2781, 57.62257)*

This is the CamCoord (coordinates of camera position) -> *vector3(1690.352,-213.4403,58.86302)*

[This is where the Yaw and pitch should go using the relative yaw and pitch position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5HO5.jpg)

```
SetGameplayCamRelativePitch(pitch, 2.0)
SetGameplayCamRelativeHeading(yaw)
```

These two functions do set the position of the crosshair based on player heading (So what direction the player is facing 360°).

The heading of the picture is around 137.53

Comment: `yaw = (math.deg(yaw) + 180) % 360 - 180`, the same for pitch

Comment: I obtain different numbers but yet the position isn't correct. Maybe the atan2 is calculated in a wrong way? @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: Show a few examples (input dx dy dz and the output you want to get)

Comment: I just added an example with the data @EgorSkriptunoff thank you for your help in advance

Comment: The values of `yaw` and `pitch` are not clear from the picture.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The Heading (Yaw) is 137.53. But since the result I'm looking for are not absolute but relative, why would you need the absolute yaw and pitch?

Comment: `The Heading (Yaw) is 137.53`, OK, and what is the value of `yaw` calculated by the Lua code?

Comment: I just have to know where to include the current player heading in the formula. Like saying that my current heading is the 0. Anyways in the formula the Yaw is around 90° but it changes everytime I click